# SQL query to select event sessions

Tags: sql, analytics

Suppose we have a table with two columns `user_id` and `event_time`, representing events which might occur in an application.

We'd like to write an SQL query that finds user sessions. Sessions are defined to be something along the lines of a series of consecutive events for a particular where none of the events are separated by more than some amount of time (similar to how `Google Analytics` defines a session).

For example, if we had the following table:

```
    user_id | time 
   ---------+------
          1 |    1
          1 |    2
          1 |    3
          1 |    4
          1 |   20
          1 |   22
          1 |   26
          1 |   28
          1 |   30
          2 |    2
          2 |    4
          2 |    6
          3 |   15
          3 |   30
```

We might produce the following output:

```
    user_id | start | end
   ---------+------+------
          1 |     1 |   4
          1 |    20 |  30
          2 |     2 |   6
          3 |    15 |  15
          3 |    30 |  30
```

Comment: It's simple to reduce this problem to a problem of merging intervals; because we can just select out intervals of events separated by no more than 5 time units. We can then make a matrix of overlapping intervals, but it's not clear whether it's possible to then merge those overlapping intervals in any obvious way without a solution that is not recursive.

Comment: can't event find the logic how to identify the starting and ending points of a session based on your expected result

Comment: if there is a flag for starting and stopping ... a simple solution would be just getting the min and max of each session on that day or time

Comment: @RhianA imagine a stream of events from a single user (1), we see an event at time 1, 2, 3, 4. The next doesn't happen until 20 which is > 5 away, so we define the first session as spanning 1-4. We then hit events 20, 22, 26, 28, and 30. Because each successive event is not more  than 5 away from the last, they all belong to one session.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. i now see the logic behind...

Comment: From the `SQL` tag you used: *Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) **and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2) being used***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using MS SQL Server then you can use CTEs and Windowed functions to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @my_table TABLE (userid INT NOT NULL, timeid INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @my_table (userid, timeid)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (1, 4),
    (1, 20),
    (1, 22),
    (1, 26),
    (1, 28),
    (1, 30),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 4),
    (2, 6),
    (3, 15),
    (3, 30)

;WITH CTE_With_Previous AS
(
    SELECT
        userid,
        timeid,
        LAG(timeid) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY timeid) AS last_time
    FROM
        @my_table
),
CTE_Range_Starts AS
(
    SELECT
        userid,
        timeid,
        LEAD(timeid) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY timeid) AS next_group_start_time
    FROM CTE_With_Previous
    WHERE
        timeid - last_time > 5 OR last_time IS NULL
)
SELECT
    S.userid,
    S.timeid AS start_time,
    (SELECT MAX(MT.timeid) AS end_time FROM @my_table MT WHERE MT.userid = S.userid AND (MT.timeid < S.next_group_start_time OR S.next_group_start_time IS NULL))
FROM CTE_Range_Starts S
```

This query works by getting a result set of each row with the timeid from the previous row (ordered by timeid). That makes the math easier in the next CTE where it looks for every case where the difference between the timeid and the previous timeid is greater than 5 - which means that this is going to be the start of a new session. Along with each of these start times we find the start time of the next session (the LEAD function).

Now that we have the start times for each session along with the start times of the next session after that one in the same row we just need to get the end times for those sessions, which is simply the last timeid (MAX) before the next session.

Comment: Works on Redshift as well. Can you maybe explain this a bit?